# Foundation 5 SASS Install - Thor gem crashes

Tags: ruby, sass, zurb-foundation-5, thor

I have recently spent a LOT of time attempting to install Foundation 5 SASS on my server, but have run into a continual stream of errors. However, I have finally gotten to the point that I can narrow it down to one issue, the `thor` gem. My server was installed with the 1-click LEMP Ubuntu application stack install from Digital Ocean.

I have reset my server over 10 times, all to try different approaches. Here are some of the most recent, with the different errors that appear.

===========================================
FIRST ATTEMPT

*** PROGRAM LIST ***

```
/usr/share/nginx$ git --version
    git version 1.9.1
/usr/share/nginx$ node --version
    v0.10.25
/usr/share/nginx$ ruby --version
    ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
/usr/share/nginx$ sudo bower --version
    1.4.1

/usr/share/nginx$ gem list
    ** LOCAL GEMS **

    bundler (1.10.3)
    chunky_png (1.3.4, 1.3.3)
    compass (1.0.3)
    compass-core (1.0.3, 1.0.1)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
    ffi (1.9.8, 1.9.6)
    foundation (1.0.4)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    multi_json (1.11.0, 1.10.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.5, 0.9.4)
    rb-itnotify (0.9.5)
    sass (3.4.14)
    thor (0.19.1)
```

*** ERROR ***

```
*************:/usr/share/nginx$ foundation new [FOLDERNAME]
Creating ./[FOLDERNAME]
create html
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in 'mkdir': Permission denied -/usr/share/nginx/[FOLDERNAME] (Errno::EACCES)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in 'fu_mkdir'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in 'block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in 'reverse_each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in 'each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in 'mkdir_p'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:50:in 'block in invoke!'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb.116:in 'call'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in 'invoke_with_conflict_check'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:49:in 'invoke!'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in 'action'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:14:in 'empty_directory'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/foundation-1.0.4/lib/foundation/cli/generator.rb:126:in 'new'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27: in 'run'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in 'new'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359: in 'dispatch'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in 'start'
from /var/lib/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/foundation:4:in '<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/foundation:23:in 'load'
from /usr/local/bin/foundation.23:in '<main>'
```

===========================================
SECOND ATTEMPT

(AS ROOT)

```
adduser admin
usermod -a -G sudo admin
logout
```

(AS ADMIN)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install ruby
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
sudo apt-get install npm

git --version
    git version 1.9.1
ruby --version
    ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
node --version
    v0.10.25
nodejs --version
    v0.10.25
npm --version
    1.3.10

sudo npm install -g bower grunt-cli
bower --version
    1.4.1

gem install foundation
    Fetching: thor-0.19.1.gem (100%)
    ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems

sudo gem install foundation

sudo gem install compass
    Fetching: sass-3.4.15.gem (100%)
    Fetching: multi_json-1.11.1.gem (100%)
    Fetching: compass-core-1.0.3.gem (100%)
    Fetching: compass-import-once-1.0.5.gem (100%)
    Fetching: chunky_png-1.3.4.gem (100%)
    Fetching: rb-fsevent-0.9.5.gem (100%)
    Fetching: ffi-1.9.10.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions. This could take a while...
    ERROR: Error installing compass.
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custome_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custome_require.rb:36:in 'requre'
    from extconf.rb:4:in '<main>'
    Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection
    Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.10/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

As you can see from this time, the gem first flared up when I tried to install `foundation`, and gave the `Errno::EACCES` error. However, I "fixed" this with `sudo`, and was able to get one step further, where I completely had to stop. It seems to be the thor gem that is causing all of my issues, but I don't know anything about Ruby at all.

Could it possibly be the fact that I am using the 1-click install? Would it be better if I manually installed the LEMP stack? Also, should I install everything as root, and then try to create the Project as the sudo-enabled user?

I have posted to both the Foundation forum and the Ruby forum, but haven't been able to get anything yet.

[Foundation Forum](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/25689-foundation-5-permissions-error-cant-create-projects)

[Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6876050#new)

Please let me know if I need to include anything else!

Comment: If you think my question needs working on, please let me know why so I can fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault appears to somehow lie with user permissions. Out of desperation, I attempted to create a new foundation project from `/home/admin`, and it worked! I ran the rest of the SASS setup, and then promptly moved the folder to `/usr/share/nginx/html`, and have been working on fixing the rest of my site now.

Apparently, I do not have the necessary permissions in the `../nginx/` folder that I need (for the thor gem), but yet I do have them in the `../admin/` folder. This is because the `../admin/` folder is the one created as the home directory for my user, but the `nginx` folder was created by `root`. To fix this, I merely had to change the `nginx` permissions to `root sudo`, instead of `root root`.

Anyway, to sum it up, the problem lay with permissions, **not** with the Foundation installation process. The instructions on their page should be all that are necessary to correctly install the product.